# Summing subsets of array

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an array `farr`, size Nx*Nx.

I have a function `frk` that maps index {n,m} to an integer (approximately `Floor[Norm[{n,m}]]`)

I want to Bin all the elements in the array, according to their index and that function, and then sum them.

I am using this, but it is far too slow:

```
res = ConstantArray[0, 3*Nx];
Do[res[[frk[n,m,Nx] + 1]] += farr[[n, m]], {m, Nx}, {n, Nx}];
```

Any ideas?.. GatherBy seems almost right, but it cares about values, not indexes

Comment: What does the third argument of `frk` do?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: It's the size of the array.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I know, but what does it do there? I mean, Oded defines `frk` informally as using two arguments and then calls it with three.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and make ir more clear what  are you asking.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries it loops around using Nx - this is a discrete fourier transform, so if Nx=400, then "k=20" works for "n=20" and for n="380". The full thing:

    Floor[Norm[{Nx/2 - Abs[n - 1. - Nx/2], Nx/2 - Abs[m - 1. - Nx/2]}]

Answer (score 2):

Solved it with this, works much much faster:

```
frkidx = 1 + 
   GatherBy[Range[0, Nx*Nx - 1], 
    frk[1 + Floor[#/Nx], 1 + Mod[#, Nx], Nx] &];

res = Map[Total[farr[[#]]] &, idx];
```

(I had to flatten `farr`)